# Floating point division in Bash

Tags: linux, bash, shell, floating-point

I have a bash script which divides the numbers by 100.

```
for ((i=0; i< ${#array2[*]};  ++i))
do
    if ! [[ "${array2[$i]}" =~ ^[0-9]+$ ]]
    then
        echo "Converting time of speaker ${array2[$i]} to seconds"
    else
        array3[$i]="$((${array2[$i]}/100 ))"
        echo "${array3[$i]}"

    fi
done
```

instead of giving me answers in floating point, it gives me answer in integers. 
**How can I get the answer in floating points?**

Comment: Use an external tool, such as `bc`, `awk`, or a different scripting language.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
array3[$i]="$((${array2[$i]}/100 ))"
```

Instead of this line, you can use:

```
array3[$i]=$( bc <<< "scale=2; ${array2[$i]} / 100" )
```